# Black's formula derivation: expectation of a indicator times a random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, finance

[image]

In this derivation of Black's formula for puts, we have that $\mathbb{E}[e^X   1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}]$ somehow equals $S_0  e^{\mu + 0.5 \sigma^2} N$ (as above in the formula).

I tried breaking apart the formula into

$$\mathbb{E}[e^X   1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}]) = \mathbb{E}(e^X)\mathbb{E}(1_{e^X \leq K/S_0}) + \operatorname{Cov}(e^X,1_{e^X \leq K/S_0})$$

and ended up with

$$S_0  e^{\mu + 0.5\sigma^2}  N((\ln(K/S_0) - \mu)/\sigma) + \operatorname{Cov}(e^X, 1_{e^X \leq K/S_0})$$

by applying the MGF and standardizing the inside of the Normal

and now I'm stuck on what to do next to simplify it into the form given in step 3.

My question is how to calculate away the Covariance term to make it match last line of the circled formula, aka how do you get from step 2 to step 3 of the circled.

Comment: Please describe explicitly where is the problem, as is stays, $X$ is overloaded, we still do not know at which passage from one expression to an other one there is an unclear point. Note that the computation of an expectation like $\Bbb E[f(X)]$ are easily done by computing the integral of $f$ against the density of $X$. Also, **do not put the main part of the question in a picture**! Linked pictures get lost in time. Also, when writing an answer, pieces of mathjax can be reused. Please write a question that may be useful for the community now and after some months.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the new random variable $Y:=\exp(X)$. Then you are asked to calculate $\mathbb{E}(Y1_{Y\leq c})$ for some constant c. This boils down to evaluating the integral $\int_0^c y f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y$

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{E}(Y1_{Y\leq c})$ = $\int_0^cf_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y$ = $F_Y(c)$? Is it because after you open up the integral of $\mathbb{E}(Y1_{Y\leq c})$ you get $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}1_{Y \leq c} * f_Y(y) \mathrm{d}y$ by law of the unconscious statistician? Then you just simplify the indicator w.r.t. the integral and all is done?

Comment: nevermind: Oh it's even simpler than that - $Y1_{Y\leq c}$ is exactly $Y$ if $Y \leq c$ but is zero otherwise. Therefore its expectation on its domain is just integral from 0 to c, i see...

Comment: Yeah but that doesn't match the final answer...

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int \limits_{-\infty}^{c} y*f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y$ because it's an expectation of Y, basically?

Comment: You are right - that was a mistake. It should be $\int^c yf(y) \mathrm{d}y$